# Installed MySQL with Homebrew. What is the default database.yml configuration to connect?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, homebrew

I just installed MySQL with Homebrew.

What is the configuration in `database.yml` needed to connect to it locally on my dev machine?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `database.yml` configuration I use to connect to MySQL that has been installed using Homebrew:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: my_database_name
  username: root
  password:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```